# AngularJS not working on Spring application

Tags: angularjs, spring

I have a Spring application and I'm trying to build the the views with AngularJS, however the duble curly bracket notation doesn't work, which means bindings also don't work. Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.js"></script>
<head lang="en">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-init="code='000'">
    <div class="outer"> 
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/></p>
    <p>You wrote: {{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to load this page, I get the correct text field, but the {{name}} remains like this regardless of what I do.

Edit: I had forgotten the angular script, but I added it and the problem persists

Comment: you don't have angular js lib in your html.

Comment: I added `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></scr>` to my file, but the problem persists. is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ng-app directive, but you have not declared the testApp module. Try declaring the testApp module `angular.module('testApp', [])`

Here's your example again. It's working for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.js"></script>
<head lang="en">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="./bower_components/bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<script>
    //create the testApp module
    angular.module('testApp', []);
</script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-init="code='000'">
    <div class="outer"> 
    <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"/></p>
    <p>You wrote: {{ name }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! is that necessary for all angular applications? I don't think I saw that on other examples

Comment: In the angular quickstart example https://angularjs.org/#the-basics , they use ng-app without a module name. If you follow this approach, you don't need to declare a modlue. If you are planning on writing anything more than 10-20 lines of angular code, however, I would highly suggest making a module and using controllers to keep your code more manageable.